# Install Coldfusion 11 on IIS 7 and see error 404.0 when I try to run servlet

Tags: java, servlets, iis, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I install Coldfusion 11 on IIS 7 and see error 404.0 when try to run servlet from "index.cfm". I added:

```
.class in folder C:\ColdFusion11\wwwroot\WEB-INF\classes,

servlets configuration in C:\ColdFusion11\wwwroot\WEB-INF\web.xml,

.jar in C:\ColdFusion11\wwwroot\WEB-INF\lib,

"index.cfm" in C:\inetpub\wwwroot,
```

Servlets are java classes. "index.cfm" is run, because it located in IIS home folder(C:\inetpub\wwwroot) and when I try to go to servlet from "index.cfm" i see error 404.0. Before I work on Coldfusion 9 and it's work perfectly, but I will need to use websockets and Coldfusion 9 not support its. In Coldfusion 9, when I install it, I check "Configure web server for Coldfusion 9 applications" if see "Error 404" and it's solve problem. In 11 version I not see checkbox "Configure web server for Coldfusion 11 applications". Maybe in this is my problem. Please help!

Comment: ColdFusion 11 and ColdFusioon 9 are two different installations. Add ".clas" files in CF9, will not help in CF11. What is the URL, you are using? Have you created the connector?

Comment: Url:"http://127.0.0.1/UploadFileServlet", connector I create in "Web Server Configuration Tools"

Comment: Can you create a test cfm page first and check?

Comment: Yes, I create and add it in folder  "C:\inetpub\wwwroot" because in "C:\ColdFusion11\wwwroot\WEB-INF" it not see this "index.cfm"

Comment: what happens when you access http://127.0.0.1:port_no/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm?

Comment: Show error:"Server Error in Application "Default Web Site" HTTP error 404.0 Not found"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68918/discussion-between-anit-kumar-and-serg-bash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the built-in server of ColdFusion. Please ignore, if already enabled. You can try the following steps to enable the same:-

1. Open the cfroot\cfusion\runtime\conf\server.xml file.
2. Search for internal webserver start. Uncomment the following connector XML.

> Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool" port="8500" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8445"/>

3. Save the file, and then restart ColdFusion.

Then access 127.0.0.1:8500/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm, where 8500 is the port mention above in server.xml